# Is it possible to change command length limits in plesk scheduled task?

Tags: mariadb, hosting, centos7, vps, plesk

I have this command line which already runs into a cpanel hosting:

```
mysql -hlocalhost -e "use xxx_xx; update xxx_jshopping_manufacturers set manufacturer_publish = 0 where \`name_es-ES\` NOT IN ('BULL SOUND', 'ROYAL', 'BLACK + DECKER (ELECTROD)', 'SAMSUNG', 'DAEWOO', 'OSTER', 'WAHL', 'REMINGTON', 'BROTHER', 'CORELLE', 'SINGER', 'PANASONIC', 'FRIGIDAIRE', 'LG', 'PHILIPS ELECTRONICA', 'PIONEER', 'SONY', 'MOTOROLA', 'DEWALT', 'APPLE', 'JVC', 'MAXELL', 'WELL', 'STANLEY', 'LASKO', 'WESTINGHOUSE', 'CATA', 'FARBERWARE', 'BLACK & DECKER (HERRAM)', 'PHILIPS', 'BLAUPUNKT', 'RAYOVAC', 'BLU', 'JBL', 'BLACK & DECKER (HERRAM)','MUEBLES', 'ALTEC', 'SMART BALANCE', 'NEWLINK', 'YEZZ', 'HUAWEI', 'FORD', 'WINDMERE','DRIJA','REAL SALOON','INGCO'); select count(product_id)as '--- Product quantity ---' from xxx_jshopping_products; select \`name_es-ES\` as '--- Brands that are hidden ---' from xxx_jshopping_manufacturers where manufacturer_publish = 0;" | mailx -r sender@domain.com -s 'your site has been updated' destination@domain.com cc@domain.com
```

This command runs a query in mysql DB to hide some items and then email the results, it worked all time without issues until now that I have to move this site to a Centos / plesk hosting, I have made changes to the script to include user and password and it runs as always by clicking on the "Run now" button on the plesk scheduled task panel, however, when I click the "Ok" button to save the cron, it is given me this error

> Error: Incorrect parameter values. cmd: The command cannot be longer than 980 characters.

Is there a way to get rid of that limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible without addressing the maximum length issue.

Create a script file like this and it will run.

```
mysql -h hostname -otherParametersAsNeeded <<EOF1
  use xxx_xx;
  update xxx_database set ...
  ...
EOF1
```

Comment: Sure, that was what I use at the end, there's a limit of 999 chars length to command in cron jobs, both, cpanel and plesk, cpanel seems to chunks the command and just run the first chunk (I did not review that, just readed it  on some post) and no error is throwing so I decided to run it using a .sql file, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Make the whole of your mysql code into a bash script as I mentioned and you shall call the script within cron (or so).